# Date range restriction with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date-range

There are two input fields of type text to write a start date and end date in format mm/dd/yyy. I need a JavaScript function to check that the date range interval between those entered dates does not exceed 14 days. And the maximum date should be the current date. Is there a plugin or a fast solution for this? I tried to use the jQuery UI datepicker which would work fine, but I have a custom GetElementByClassName function which conflicts with jQuery.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you automatically display date in the second text box adding +14 so that there is no necessity to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippets should give you some ideas.

```
<script>
    var date1 = '01/14/2011';
    var date2 = '01/25/2011';

    // calculate the number of days between date1 and date2
    var daysBetween = new Date(date2).getTime() - new Date(date1).getTime();
    alert('days between = ' + daysBetween / 86400000);

    // check date3 against current date
    var now = new Date();
    var date3 = new Date('04/20/2011');
    if (date3 < now)
      alert('date3 is less than current date');

</script>
```

So to combine into a function, you could do something like this:

```
<script>
    function checkDates(date1, date2) {
        // calculate the number of days between date1 and date2
        var daysBetween = (new Date(date2).getTime() - new Date(date1).getTime()) / 86400000;

        if (daysBetween > 14)
          return false;

        var now = new Date();
        if (date2 < now)
          return false;

        return true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this problem and I found focusout function to be the best solution that match my requirement. Jquery code:

```
$("#datefield").focusout(function () {
  date = $("#datefield").val();
  if (date > "2021-06-30" || date < "2020-07-01") {
    alert("Please enter a valid date.");
    $("#datefield").val("");
  }
});
```